$X\setminus \overline{\{ x\}}$ is meet irreducible in the lattice $O(X)$.
Let $X$ be a topological space and $x\in X$ I want to show that $X\setminus \ \overline{\{ x\}}$ is meet-irreducible in the lattice $O(X)$ of open sets of $X$. This means that we want to show that $X\setminus \overline{\{ x\}}$ cannot be written as $$X\setminus  \overline{\{ x\}}=O_1\cap O_2$$
where $O_1,O_2\in O(X)$ are different from $X\setminus \ \overline{\{ x\}}$. But I don't see how.
It is clear that this means we cannot write  $ \overline{\{ x\}}=C_1\cup C_2$ where $C_i$ is a closed set being complement of $O_i$ in $X$. But what to write next.

Perhaps this is helpful.

yes that's what I meant. I will edit it.

If $\overline{{x}} = C_1 \cup C_2$, then one of $C_i$ has to contain $x$, say $x \in C_1$. But then as $C_1$ is closed and ${x} \subset C_1$, we have $\overline{{x}} \subset C_1$. But we also have $C_1 \subset C_1 \cup C_2 = \overline{{x}}$, so $C_1 = \overline{{x}}$, so $O_1 = X \setminus \overline{{x}}$, a contradiction.

I will accept it as an answer. Thank you very much!
